# How to access a dynamically created object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating an object dynamically. I am wondering how do I access it? Some of these objects need to be hidden through other means than a click (programmatically, button clicks, links, etc). So I dont think I could use .on. How would I go about accessing these to hide them?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('body').append('<div id="testdiv">Test DIV</div>');

}); 

$('#testdiv').hide();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You reverse your logic. Instead of `.append()`, you should use `.appendTo()`

```
var myRef = $("<div id=\"testdiv\">Test DIV</div>").appendTo( document.body );
```

That way, you can keep a reference to that newly created *DOM node* / *jQuery object*.

```
myRef.hide();
```

---

It's *always better* to store a cached reference into a variable, so you can access a node from pure *ECMA land*, so to speak. The need to *re-query* for a DOM node, is just much less effiecient.

<sup>One word of caution: variables declared by `var` do only own *function scope*. That means if you want to access that reference from "outside" of your *ready handler*, you would need to declare that variable in a parent context for instance.</sup>

Comment: ... or just chain the `hide()` after the `appendTo()`.

Comment: Should probably clarify that the `myRef.hide()` cannot be outside doc ready like the op currently has `$("#testdiv").hide()`

Comment: @Esailija: I don't think that is in the scope of this answer (javascript very fundamentals). I don't know the OPs app structure, namespacing, etc.

Comment: I agree with @Esailija, just looking at the code in the question. An inference could be made.

Answer (score 2):

What you've got already should work, except you'll need to move `$('#testdiv').hide();` inside the document ready (so you're not calling it before the element is created).

The other answer is a cleaner way to do it, and the way that I would do it.